# CET timezone strings to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
date_cet                           col1
---------------------------------------
2021-10-31 02:00:00+02:00           7.0
2021-10-31 02:00:00+02:00           7.0
2021-10-31 02:00:00+02:00           8.0
2021-10-31 02:00:00+01:00          10.0
2021-10-31 02:00:00+01:00          11.0
```

I have a data frame that has columns looking similar to this. This data is imported from SQL into a Pandas data frame, and when I print out the `dtypes` I can see that the `date_cet` column is `object`. Since I need it further on, I want to convert it to a datetime object. However, the stuff I've tried just doesn't work, and I think it might have something to do with 1) the timezone difference and 2) the fact that this date is where DST changes (i.e. the `+01:00` and `+02:00`).

I've tried to do stuff like this:

```
import datetime as dt

df["new_date"] = [dt.datetime.strptime(str(x), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z") for x in df["date_cet"]]

df['new_date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date_cet'])
```

and a hand full of other stuff.

The first gives an error of:

```
ValueError: time data '2021-10-31 02:00:00+02:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z'
```

And the last:

```
ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True
```

Basically, I have no idea how to fix this. I just need this column to become a datetime[ns, Europe/Copenhagen] type of column, but everything I've done so far doesn't work.

Comment: There's no space between `%S` and `%z` in the datetime string…

Comment: Please try the format `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the datetime string ('2021-10-31 02:00:00+02:00') there is no space between `%S` and `%z`

try to change to this format - `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z"`

```
import datetime as dt

df["new_date"] = [dt.datetime.strptime(str(x), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z") for x in df["date_cet"]]

df['new_date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date_cet'])
```

Update:

to fix the error try adding - `utc=True`:

```
import datetime as dt

df["new_date"] = [dt.datetime.strptime(str(x), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z") for x in df["date_cet"]]

df['new_date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date_cet'], utc=True)
```

you can do this by one line:

```
df['new_date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date_cet'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z", utc=True)
```

Comment: Yeah, okay that was a blunder. However, if I do that I get the error `ValueError: Array must be all same time zone`. So I'm guessing that the issue is because of this particular date where the DST actually changes. Can that be fixed?

Comment: look at my update - tell me if its ok ;) @DenverDang

Comment: If `df['date_cet']` is a column, you can do this in only one line: `df['new_date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date_cet'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z", utc=True)`.